# Private car sale agreement with 6 months warranty

Tags: united-kingdom

Bought a used car through Facebook market and we made a mistake.

On inspection we figured out there was something wrong with one part of car but we were not sure. We offered X amount but seller offered X + £500 with 6 month's warranty on if something major fault comes up in car. We accepted it.

On sale invoice which is on letter head of seller's company which deals with something other then cars, they wrote that car is sold for this amount and included 6 months warranty T&C. In invoice they didn't provided any T&Cs.

After 2 weeks this part started showing signs of a serious problem. On inspection from 3 garages, they all suggest it needs replacement as soon as possible.

Now spoken to seller they say warranty was only for car's tyres which obliviously not true as invoice is for car not tyres.

In advert they said car is in perfect condition and full service history, both statements were incorrect.

I read on internet private car sales, buyer don't have many rights, however I am unable to find relevant cases where seller provided written signed agreement with 6 months warranty. Is there a case for me ?

Comment: Don't pay to get the car fixed... yet. You may be able to get a court to void the sale and return the money to you (and the car to the seller) but it would be difficult to recover any money you put into the car while it was in your possession.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a case for me ?

Yes, you have a valid claim of *breach of contract*.

> Now spoken to seller they say warranty was only for car's tyres which
>   obliviously not true as invoice is for car not tyres.

You are right. And it makes no sense for the seller to allege that the additional £500 only covers warranty for tires, since you could buy a set of new (meaning unused) tires for less than amount.

Take a screenshot of the advertisement, and ask the car mechanic(s) for some written record or report of what serious issues he (or they) found. The nature of the issues would reflect that these most likely predate the purchase, whence a court should find that the warranty is enforceable.

To preclude the seller's denial that you [timely] approached him in this regard, it would help if you have evidence --in writing-- of his disavowal(s) of the warranty.

P.S: I don't know the UK procedural law but, if you commence any proceedings on your own, ask a friend or relative to proofread your papers. Your omission of words makes your inquiry hard to read.